# GUI on windows running linux script on networked Linux machine?

Tags: linux, windows, user-interface, ssh, putty

I want to run a shell script on a networked linux machine from a windows based GUI.

I have the shell script, but what's the easiest way to develop the GUI to run that script on a networked linux machine?

Comment: What programming language do you want to use?

Comment: I feel comfortable with using Visual Studio for Visual Basic or C++.  I'm just looking for the best way to have a button command in a Windows GUI sitting on someones PC launch a shell script that is sitting on a linux machine on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

Shell scripts alone do not have a default gui tool, However, the QT framework ([QT Creator](http://wiki.qt.io/Category:Tools::QtCreator)) is a great place to start developing a gui that can run either on windows or linux. If you're uncomfortable converting your script to C++, you could also look a the [pyQT](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) project  as well which combines the python language with the QT framework andalso works well in both windows/linux.

Comment: any ideas on what to look for as far as the best way to have a button command in a Windows GUI sitting on someones PC launch a shell script that is sitting on a linux machine on the same network?